# Sumar resultados PHP

Tags: php

He buscado pero no encuentro la solución.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive">
 <thead class="text-center">
<th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
<th scope="col">Producto</th>
<th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
<th scope="col">Total</th>
<th scope="col">Acción</th>
 </thead>
<?php 
 foreach($_SESSION["carrito"] as $c):
      $products = $cnx->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto=$c[id_producto]");
 $r = $products->fetch_object();
     ?>
 <tr>
 <td scope="row"><?php echo $c["cantidad"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $r->nombre;?></td>
<td>$ <?php echo $r->preciototal; 
  ?></td>
    <td>$ <?php echo $c["cantidad"]*$r->preciototal; ?></td>
<td style="width:260px;">
 <?php
   $found = false;
     foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $c) { if($c["id_producto"]==$r->id_producto){ $found=true; break; }}
     ?>
    <a href="../carrito/actions/delfromcart.php?id=<?php echo $c["id_producto"];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
  </td>
 </tr>

 <?php 

    echo $r->preciototal;
 endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

Al imprimir `$r->preciototal;` da los resultados del foreach general.

Es decir, tengo 2 productos, da resultados de preciototal de 2 productos.

Quiero que esos `"preciototal"` de cada producto, esten sumados con sus cantidades y entre si.. asi dando el TOTAL de todo.

Es decir:

```
$producto1 = 100;
$cantidadP1 = 2;
$totalP1 = 200;
$producto2 = 200;
$cantidadP2 = 3;
$totalP2 = 600;
$total = 800;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente crea una variable que sume esas totales, algo asi:

```
$suma_total = 0;
```

y luego en el foreach sumas los totales:

```
$suma_total += $r->preciototal;
```

y fuera del foreach imprimes la variable total

```
echo $suma_total
```